# AngularJS badcfg on 'GET' request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an API that returns data to AngularJS based on a given ID, however, when the data is returned as JSON, AngularJS is throwing a 'badcfg' error, which I understand to be due to the format of the returned data, but can't figure out how to fix it...

Factory:

```
app.factory('Companies', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api.php/companies/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
        'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'save': {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: true,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        }},
        'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
    });

});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("ViewCompaniesController", ['$scope', 'Companies', '$routeParams', function($scope, Companies, $routeParams) {
    $scope.title = 'View';

    var companyId = $routeParams.id;

    var theCompany = Companies.get({ id: companyId }, function() {
        console.log(theCompany);
    });
}]);
```

Error:

> Error in resource configuration for action `Error in resource
>   configuration for action`{0}`. Expected response to contain an {1}
>   but got an {2} (Request: {3} {4})`. Expected response to contain an
>   get but got an object (Request: array GET)

Could anybody help resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [the ng-doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) you're not useing your defined request:

```
 var theCompany = Companies.query({ id: companyId }, function() {
        console.log(theCompany);
    });
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Silly me for forgetting to change that.
Now I'm setting $scope.company = theCompany, and doing {{ company }} prints out all the values, but doing, for example {{ company.id }} doesn't print the id?

Comment: you should open a new question for that. but from my opinion it seems like you're not updating the company or storing it corectly?